# how to open a save dialog popup in IE11 using Robot

Tags: selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

[image]

I am performing my testing on IE11 and can't use any other browser.
While execution I am getting download pop up and want to download file in TestResult folder.

How can I achieve this using Robot ? I have also read about AutoIT but not sure as I am quite new to these. Please tell me the easiest way.

currently working on testng framework and stuck in download part.

Comment: enhanced the title to make the question clearer